# Why does jsLint in VS generate: A '<noscript>' must be within '< body head noframes >?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, jslint

The basic structure of my page is

```
   body
       div id="content"
          nav
          article id="spa"
             noscript
```

I searched the [docs page](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html) for noscript but found nothing. I'm not even sure what the error message is suggesting I should do since the noscript tag is already inside a body tag. The page displays and works properly. When js support is turned off the appropriate message is displayed. I tried moving the noscript tag to just below the body tag but the same warning is issued.

As part of posting this message I took the contents of my html page, including the open and close body tags, pasted it into jsFiddle and it came up clean. This may be specific to Visual Studio 2012 and the JSLint.VS2012 extension. I also didn't see a way in the JsLint options to disable this check.

Comment: Are you sure JSLint is what's generating that error? It doesn't usually look at HTML at all…

Comment: In the Errors Tab the warnings get tagged with JsLint or JsHint and this one says JsLint. In the JsLint For Visual Studio v1.4.2.0 dialog box it has checkboxes for Validating HTML, CSS and JS. Maybe it's unique to this JSLint.VS2012 extension.

Comment: Yep, there doesn't appear to be anything in the [JSLint code](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint) targeting NOSCRIPT.  Unfortunately, [unlike JSLint.VS2010](http://jslint4vs2010.codeplex.com/), I don't think [JSLint.VS2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1a417c37-4d6f-43ca-b753-6ea6eb5041fd) is open source.  I'll give JetBrains' dotPeek a try and post a real answer if I get a chance, but I *think* @duskwuff and you are right; it's the plugin, not JSLint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That warning does indeed come from JSLint, although not the latest version – warnings for HTML and CSS code were removed from JSLint [quite recently](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/commit/267939b9168419312782a8533e35c60243215d56).

I'm not sure why JSLint insists a `<noscript>` tag can only go in those places. The [HTML 5 spec says](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#the-noscript-element) it can go anywhere "phrasing content" is allowed, which is basically all the main content.

JSLint is very *very* picky. So while it's possible the warning exists because some legacy browsers have trouble with `<noscript>` in other locations... it's equally likely it's just a personal pet peeve of JSLint's creator, Douglas Crockford.

If you want to eliminate all JSLint warnings and you can't move the `<noscript>` tag up to the body, you could always use a regular visible element that's hidden by JS code if the JS gets a chance to run. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jJNDa/

Comment: The strange thing is I do have it inside a body tag. I took your advice and just used JS to hide it.

Comment: That's definitely odd. If I use [this test HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/y8Bsc/) then I don't get any JSLint errors with the slightly older "2012-01-13" edition. Are there any other warnings on the file? E.g. is it possible there are unbalanced tags or anything?